# Unable to upload attachments in the yahoo mail

Tags: browser, attachments, xiaomi

I am currently using the Xiaomi Redmi 1S device with Android 4.3 operating system.I log-in through yahoo in my mi browser and try to attach an image.The problem comes in attaching an image under the attachments option.

Steps Followed to attach an image:-

1)Clicked on Attachment icon under the mail.

2)The browse page loads and i click on browse and select the image which i want to send.

3)After selecting the image it instead opens another blank page.

4)Tried going back and re-select the image but again upon selecting the image it opens a new blank page.

I cannot pin point where exactly the problem is(whether the WiFi or the browser).

**Note**:-The image gets selected under the browse option very rarely(i.e in 4 times i try the image gets selected only once and it get's difficult if i try to attach multiple images )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original answer got a downvote, despite being a valid suggestion. :P

So, I'm going to try a different answer.

You are using a Xiaomi device, and you probably won't find a lot of Mi users here. [They (MIUI)](http://en.miui.com/forum.php) have their own forum, and you will probably find better support there.

The Mi browser you talk of is not available in Google Play. So, I'm willing to bet it's a custom browser packaged with the MIUI ROM, and I'm willing to bet it's not a very good one, given the problem you just described.

So, I'd suggest that you install a 3rd-party browser like Dolphin Browser. In the screenshot below, you can see that the image was attached even if Yahoo Mail was either in desktop mode (left) or in mobile mode (right).

Otherwise, just save yourself the trouble and just install the Yahoo Mail app.

[image]

Comment: It seems that the whole MIUI5 has the same problem.(Throughout the device where ever there is an attachment option available the whole process of adding attachment has to be done twice)

Comment: @user285oo6 Try a different custom ROM then?

Answer (score -1):

If the website is giving you problems, why not use the [Yahoo Mail app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail&hl=en) instead?

[image: yahoo mail app]